# Scientific notation to integers

Tags: python, python-3.7

I have a file in which values are in scientific notation 3.198304894802781462e+00 . I want to convert these in integers. I have tried this:

```
data = [int(float(number))
            for line in open('data.txt', 'r')
                for number in line.split()]
```

Error:

```
could not convert string to int: '1.874475383557408747e+01,3.627623082212955374e+00,9.037237691778705084
```

Comment: You just need to omit last 4 letters(e+01)?

Comment: You need to split on ``,``, not whitespace.

Comment: Are you really sure you want integers from this data set? The scientific notation may not be the only problem you might have with that. You'll be throwing away a bunch of digits. Your first number, `1.874475383557408747e+01` is in non-scientific notation, `18.74475383557408747`. Are you sure all those digits after the decimal place are not significant?

Answer (score 1):

you can use the context manager to read from your file:

```
data = []
with open('data.txt', 'r') as fp:
    for line in fp.readlines():
        for number in line.split(','):
            data.append(int(float(number.strip())))
```

if you want to append the data list to your file:

```
with open('data.txt', 'a') as fp:
    fp.write(",".join(str(e) for e in data))
```

Comment: you want to append in the file the `data` list?

Comment: @taliafrasat try now

Comment: its giving SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing

Comment: @taliafrasat I just forgot to close the last parenthesis, try now

Answer (score 1):

Judging by your error message, your numbers are delimited by `,`, not whitespace. You must therefore use `line.split(',')` instead.

```
with open('data.txt', 'r') as in_stream:
    data = [
        int(float(number))
        for line in in_stream
        for number in line.split(',')
    ]
```

Answer (score 0):

try something like this. you need to split the string and then apply the float function on every item:

```
a = '1.874475383557408747e+01,3.627623082212955374e+00,9.037237691778705084'
b = a.split(',')
print(b)

for n in b:
    print(float(n))
```

or simply:

```
res = [float(n) for n in a.split(',')]
```

I assumed that you have your data as string but from your example this should work:

```
data = [int(float(number))
            for line in open('data.txt', 'r')
                for number in line.split(',')]
```